# update an app in App Store in my case

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app released to App Store.

Now I have a new iOS project which originally created as a new app with different bundle id than the app on App Store.

If I want to release the new iOS project app as an update of the app already in App Store instead of a new app. Is it so that I just need to change the bundle id of my new project to be the same as the app in App Store? Is there anything else I need to take care of?

Oh, and I need to generated new provisioning profile since the bundle id changed right?

Comment: Yes, the bundle id is all that matters.

Comment: you should also check the Build number to be bigger than the App Store version.

Comment: @mkhoshpour not `Build` number but `Version` number.